# Does the bee move very fast in the very first frame of the game?

Tags: sfml, frame-rate

Does the bee move very fast in the very first frame of the game? I think the `Clock` object when it is declared, the clock starts automatically as [this documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Clock.php#abbc959c7830ca7c3a4da133cb506d3fd) says. And in the very first iteration of the loop, the clock.restart function returns the elapsed time since the clock was started or restarted, and it's a very quick moment so that it makes the bee move strangely fast from other frames moving forward, I guess. In other frames, the bee moves smoothly and nicely.

```
// Include important libraries here
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
// Make code easier to type with "using namespace"
using namespace sf;
// This is where our game starts from
int main()
{
    // Create a video mode object
    VideoMode vm(1920, 1080);
    // Create and open a window for the game
    RenderWindow window(vm, "Timber!!!", Style::Fullscreen);
    // Prepare the bee
    Texture textureBee;
    textureBee.loadFromFile("graphics/bee.png");
    Sprite spriteBee;
    spriteBee.setTexture(textureBee);
    spriteBee.setPosition(0, 800);
    // Is the bee currently on screen?
    bool beeActive = false;

    // Variables to control the time itself
    Clock clock;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        /*
        *****************************************
        Handle the player's input
        *****************************************
        */
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }
        /*
        *****************************************
        Update the scene
        *****************************************
        */
        // Measure time
        Time dt = clock.restart();
        // Set up the bee
        if (!beeActive)
        {
            // How fast is the bee?
            srand((int)time(0));
            beeSpeed = (rand() % 200) + 200;
            // How high can the bee fly
            srand((int)time(0) * 10);
            float height = (rand() % 500) + 500;
            spriteBee.setPosition(2000, height);
            beeActive = true;
        }
        else
            // Move the bee
        {
            spriteBee.setPosition(
                spriteBee.getPosition().x -
                (beeSpeed * dt.asSeconds()),
                spriteBee.getPosition().y);
            // Has the bee reached the left-hand side of the screen?
            if (spriteBee.getPosition().x < -100)
            {
                // Set it up to be a whole new bee next frame
                beeActive = false;
            }
        }
        /*
        *****************************************
        Draw the scene
        *****************************************
        */
        // Clear everything from the last frame
        window.clear();
        // Draw the insect
        window.draw(spriteBee);
        // Show everything we just drew
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that the first time isn't reliable due to variable initialization between creating the clock & reading it, you can add a basic check that zeros the clock back out on the first time through your loop:

```
// note: earlier code omitted - all of that can stay the same

Clock clock;
bool firstTimeThrough = true;
while (window.isOpen())
{
    /*
    *****************************************
    Handle the player's input
    *****************************************
    */
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
    {
        window.close();
    }
    /*
    *****************************************
    Update the scene
    *****************************************
    */
    // Measure time
    Time dt = clock.restart();
    if(firstTimeThrough)
    {
         dt = clock.restart();
         firstTimeThrough = false;
    }

    // note: remaining code omitted - all of that can stay the same
```

The documentation for `restart` says:

> This function puts the time counter back to zero. It also returns the time elapsed since the clock was started.

On the first time through (and only the first time through), the clock gets reset twice, so the resulting time should either be zero or very close to zero. Because the `firstTimeThrough` flag is true on the first pass through the loop, the remaining iteration should behave as usual.

Comment: There must be some misunderstanding about the working of the code - I thought it worked that way, but it wasn't. When the clock was started in the first place, the bee didn't move in the very first frame rate but set up the bee's speed and the bee's height randomly. Therefore, the code has no problem making the bee move weirdly fast in the very first frame of the game loop. The original code worked fine. I think there shouldn't be any fixes or improvements.